# How are the union members stored?

Tags: c, endianness, unions

```
union test
{
 int i;
 char ch;
}t;
int main()
{
 t.ch=20;
}
```

Suppose `sizeof(int)==2` and let the memory addresses allocated for t are 2000, 2001.
Then where is 20 i.e. `t.ch` stored - at 2000 or 2001 or depends on endianness of machine?

Comment: I'm not sure if endian-ness has anything to do with where a union is stored... don't all union types store at the same location (i.e., at the zero offset)? (Good question though!)

Comment: 2001 is unlikely, since unaligned memory access is either slow or forbidden depending on the architecture.

Comment: @Platinum Azure : if we simply define int a=20; then doesn't it depend on endianness where 20 is stored ?

Comment: @Happy Mittal: No, because you just say that it uses two bytes (both 2000 and 2001 in your example) regardless. Now, whether the high bits (representing the 16 and 4 place) are in 2000 or 2001 DOES depend on endian-ness, but the fact remains that whichever byte contains the set bits, the other one is still unusable because it's part of the `int` type's storage space.

Comment: @platinum Azure : Sorry I couldn't understand what do you meant by "16 and 4 place". Moreover I am saying that if I do this : 
int a=20;
printf("%d",* (char*)&a);
Then doesn't the output depend on endian-ness i.e. whether 20 is stored at 2000 or 2001 ?

Comment: The number 20 is represented in 16-bit binary as `00000000 00010100`, i.e., the 4 bit and the 16 bit are 1 and those add to 20. Now, the way I wrote that is "big endian" as you probably know, because the most significant (big) byte comes first. So in little endian we would have a representation of `00010100 00000000`. Notice that in both cases, 2 bytes are required... and in your example, they WILL both start at address 2000. So the entire 16-bit number "20" uses both bytes anyway, and we say it's stored in address 2000. The only difference is where the 1 bits go.

Comment: ok. I understand, but please tell about my code in above comment. Does the output of printf depend on endian-ness ?

Comment: It shouldn't, no. A C compiler for a particular architecture would know that either the first byte or the last byte is the lowest byte, and it would use that to determine what bits to use for an int-to-char conversion. That's for just the value conversion though; for your address conversion, I can virtually guarantee it will just use 2000 no matter what because like I said, the `20` value is stored starting at byte 2000, and the cast to `(char *)` merely forces the pointer to point to one byte.

Comment: In other words... unless you actually try to mess with addressing semantics, code should **basically** execute the same whether or not you are using big- or little-endian architecture.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: careful: in the `printf` the cast is not from `int` to `char` (where the compiler must keep the value, not the representation), but from `int *` (that comes from `&a`) to `char *`, so the first byte of the `a` (which globally is set to 20) is interpreted as a `char` would be. This thing should depend on endianness.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Originally the comment did use a `char` conversion; it was edited later. And yes, it depends on endianness, because he's messing with addressing semantics. I don't see why he cares so much about where it's stored though: it still uses 2 bytes.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: uh, sorry, I saw only the corrected version, so I didn't know your answer was indeed correct at the time it was written.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The C99 standard (§6.7.2.1.14) says:

> The size of a union is sufficient to contain the largest of its members. The value of at
>    most one of the members can be stored in a union object at any time. ***A pointer to a
>   union object, suitably converted, points to each of its members*** (or if a member is a bit-
>   field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.

*(emphasis added)*

The bold statement actually says that each member of the union has the same address, so they all "begin" at the same address. `t`, as `t.ch` as `t.i`, should be at address 2000, thus `t.ch` overlaps with the first byte (in address order) of `t.i`.

What this means in terms of "what do I get if I try to read `t.i` after setting `t.c`" in the real world depends on platform endianness, and in facts trying to read a member of a union when you wrote in another one is Unspecified Behavior according to the C standard (§6.2.6.1.6/7, restated at §J.1.1).

---

What helps more to understand the endianness of the machine (at least, I think it's more straightforward to understand) is to have a union like this:

```
union
{
    int i;
    unsigned char ch[sizeof(i)];
} t;
```

doing

```
t.i=20;
```

and then looking what's inside the two chars at `t.ch`. If you are on a little-endian machine you'll get `t.ch[0]==20` and `t.ch[1]==0`, and the opposite if you're on a big-endian machine (if `sizeof(int)==2`). Notice that, as already said, this is an implementation specific detail, the standard does not even mention endianness.

To make it even clearer: if you have a 2-byte `int` var set to 20, on a little-endian machine, dumping the memory associated to it in address-order, you'll get (in hexadecimal representation, bytes split by space):

```
14 00
```

while on a big-endian machine you'll get

```
00 14
```

The big-endian representation looks "more right" from our point of view, because in the little endian representation the bytes that make the whole `int` are stored in reverse order.

---

> Moreover I am saying that if I do this:

```
int a=20;
printf("%d",* (char*)&a);
```

> Then doesn't the output depend on endian-ness i.e. whether 20 is stored at 2000 or 2001 ?

Yes, here it does, but in your question you're asking another thing; this looks more *my* example.

Comment: Thanks Matteo. Actually you and Platinum Azure are saying opposite things, so I was confused.

Comment: @Happy Mittal: As I explained in my latest comment but this, I was using your old comment which had an int-to-char conversion. The fact remains: a sixteen-bit number represented by the literal `20` is still stored in BOTH bytes, no matter what endianness your architecture uses. It's just that one byte or the other will be zero. If you were to store a number like `257`, both bytes will be non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

test would take two bytes, and so would be allocated at address 2000, 2002, etc. And any value for each instance of the union would be stored starting at that base address.

Each member of the union would be stored at the same address for that instance of the union. That's why you can only store one type of value in a union at the same time. Therefore, unions occupy the number of bytes required for the largest member.