# How to make int from char[4]? (in C)

Tags: c, casting

I have char a[4] and in it:
`a[0] = 0x76`
`a[1] = 0x58`
`a[2] = 0x02`
`a[3] = 0x00`
And I want print it as `int`, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: As your tags indicate I recommend you do some casting.

Comment: Ya i tryed, but it don't work.
Thanks for @djf for edit my question.

Comment: *"Ya i tryed, but it don't work"*  What exactly did you try?  what does `don't work` mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works, but gives different results depending on the size of int, endian and so on..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char a[4];
    a[0] = 0x76;
    a[1] = 0x58;
    a[2] = 0x02;
    a[3] = 0x00;
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)a));
    return 0;
}
```

This is cleaner but you still have endian/size problems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    char c[4];
    int i;
} raw_int;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    raw_int i;
    i.c[0] = 0x76;
    i.c[1] = 0x58;
    i.c[2] = 0x02;
    i.c[3] = 0x00;
    printf("%d\n", i.i);
    return 0;
}
```

To force a certain endianness, build the `int` manually:

```
int i = (0x00 << 24) | (0x02 <<< 16) | (0x58 << 8) | (0x76);
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Comment: +1, nice.  For more on the endian issues with the union approach, see [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540638/how-are-the-union-members-stored).

Comment: The union approach has trouble if sizeof(int) != 4.  `printf("%d\n", i.i)` prints a half-defined int if sizeof(int) == 8.  Suggest `typedef union { char c[sizeof(int)]; ...` and `raw_int i; i.i = 0; i.c[0] = 0x76; ...`. Sadly, this still has trouble with sizeof(int) == 2.

Answer (score 7):

I think a union is the appropriate way to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union char_int {
    char chars[4];
    int32_t num;
};

int main() {
    union char_int tmp;

    tmp.chars[0] = 0x76;
    tmp.chars[1] = 0x58;
    tmp.chars[2] = 0x02;
    tmp.chars[3] = 0x00;
    printf("%d\n", tmp.num);
}
```

Comment: I think you want `printf(PRId32 "\n", tmp.num)`.  `printf("%d\n", tmp.num)` would have trouble should sizeof(int) != 4.

Comment: @chux  yes `PRIu32` is good, but your printf shoud be `printf("%"PRIu32"", tmp.num );`  you forgot `%`.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan Agreed. `"%"PRIu32"\n"`.  Pesky things those '%'.

Comment: @chux, you're absolutely correct it should be `"%"PRIu32"\n"`, however, I did handle the `sizeof(int) != 4` by using `int32_t` in my union. If I can't rely on `sizeof(int32_t) == 4` I've got bigger problems.

Comment: My concern about sizeof(int) != 4 was only directed at the "%d" not matching tmp.num.  BTW: I think to print the `int`, as requested by the OP, may be done via `printf("%d\n", (int) tmp.num)` as the cast would deal with `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int32_t)`.

Answer (score 2):

Is the value stored in the array in big-endian or little-endian order?  The portable way to do it is based on shift and mask, noting that in the general case, some of the high-order bits will be set and your plain `char` type might be signed or unsigned.

#### Little-endian

```
int i = (a[3] << 24) | ((a[2] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((a[1] & 0xFF) << 8) | (a[0] & 0xFF);
```

#### Big-endian

```
int i = (a[0] << 24) | ((a[1] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((a[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (a[3] & 0xFF);
```

You can change those so that each term is consistently of the form `((a[n] & 0xFF) << m)`.  If you know that plain `char` is unsigned, you can drop the mask operations.  You can also use a cast: `unsigned char *u = (unsigned char *)a;` and then dereference `u` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Other option can be using bitwise operators `|` and `<<` left shift, as follows (to understand read comments):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char a[4];
  int32_t  i = 0;  // 32 bits = 4 bytes
  a[0] = 0x76;
  a[1] = 0x58;
  a[2] = 0x02;
  a[3] = 0x00;

  i = 0;   // initial  value must be `0`
  i = i | a[0] << ( 3 * 8); // 0x76 => 0x76 00 00 00, gives i = 0x76 00 00 00  
  i = i | a[1] << ( 2 * 8); // 0x58 => 0x00 58 00 00, gives i = 0x76 58 00 00
  i = i | a[2] << ( 1 * 8); // 0x02 => 0x00 00 02 00, gives i = 0x76 58 02 00
  i = i | a[3] << ( 0 * 8); // 0x02 => 0x02   
                            //      => 0x00 00 00 02, gives i = 0x76 58 02 00 

  printf("Hex: %x\nDec: %d \n", i, i);
  return 0;
}
```

ouput:

```
$ gcc  -Wall -pedantic yy.c 
$ ./a.out 
Hex: 76580200            <- "hex decimal"
Dec: 1985479168          <- "decimal"
```

Notice: `i = i | a[3] << ( 0 * 8);` can be just `i = i | a[3];`, I written like that to keep code uniform.

**Edit:**

Oh you can just do it like:

```
i = 0 | 
     a[0] << ( 3 * 8) | 
     a[1] << ( 2 * 8) |
     a[2] << ( 1 * 8) |
     a[3] << ( 0 * 8);
```

Look here:[Codepade](http://codepad.org/PbQ9fVDJ) for working code.

Comment: You didn't try with any char larger than 0x80

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read it as a big- or little-endian integer, just do some bit shifting:

```
char a[4] = {0x76, 0x58, 0x02, 0x00};

// Big-endian:
uint32_t x = ((uint8_t)a[0] << 24) | ((uint8_t)a[1] << 16) | ((uint8_t)a[2] << 8) | (uint8_t)a[3];

// Little-endian:
uint32_t y = (uint8_t)a[0] | ((uint8_t)a[1] << 8) | ((uint8_t)a[2] << 16) | ((uint8_t)a[3] << 24);
```

If you want to read it as a native-endian integer, you can either cast the array to a pointer to an integer and dereference that.  Note that the former is allowed **only** for `char` arrays -- for any other types, doing so breaks C's strict aliasing rules, so that would not be safe or portable.  For example:

```
char a[4] = {0x76, 0x58, 0x02, 0x00};

// Cast to pointer to integer and dereference.  This is only allowed if `a' is an
// array of `char'.
uint32_t x = *(uint32_t *)a;
```

Alternatively, you can use a union, or just `memcpy()` the data directly.  Both of these are safe and portable, as long as a `char` is 8 bits (its size in bits is given by the macro `CHAR_BIT`).

```
char a[4] = {0x76, 0x58, 0x02, 0x00};
uint32_t x;

// Copy the data directly into x
memcpy(&x, a, sizeof(x));

// Use a union to perform the cast
union
{
    char a[4];
    uint32_t x;
} u;
memcpy(u.a, a, sizeof(a));
// u.x now contains the integer value
```

Note that I've used `uint32_t` in all of the examples above, since an `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes on all systems.  The type `uint32_t` is defined in the header file `<stdint.h>`, and if it's defined by your compiler, it's guaranteed to be 32 bits wide.

Comment: Don't you want `((uint32_t)a[0] << 24)`, etc. instead of `((uint8_t)a[0] << 24)`?

Comment: @chux: No.  If `char` is signed, then negative values get promoted incorrectly, e.g. the byte `0xaa` gets sign-extended to `0xffffffaa`, when instead we wanted `0x000000aa`.  The operands of the `<<` operators get promoted to `unsigned int` before applying the operator (the default integer promotions), so there's no worry of the shifting causing an overflow of the 8-bit value.

Comment: I see your char to int to uint32_t issue.  My concern was if sizeof(int) < 4.  Then does not `(uint8_t)a[0] << 24` become 0 or UB?  I suppose in the OP case, it can be _assumed_ sizeof(int) >= 4.

Comment: @chux: Yeah, I suppose if `sizeof(int) < 4`, then the `<< 24` will overflow.  So in that case, you'd have to write something like `(uint32_t)(uint8_t)a[0]` for each byte to be fully portable.