# Portable way of splitting n-byte integer into single bytes

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, portability

The problem is simple:
Take an 32-bit or 64-bit integer and split it up to send over an (usually)1-byte interface like uart, spi or i2c.

To do this I can easily use bit masking and shifting to get what I want. However, I want this to be portable that will work on big and little endian, but also make it work for platforms that don't discard bits but [rotate through carry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_through_carry)(masking gets rid of excess bits right?).

Example code:

```
uint32_t value;
uint8_t buffer[4];
buffer[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
buffer[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
buffer[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
buffer[3] = value & 0xFF;
```

I want to guarantee this works on any platform that supports 32 bit integers or more. I don't know if this is correct.

Comment: Shifting and masking *is* endian-proof.

Comment: Code is good and  portable to modern machines. "make it work for platforms that don't discard bits but rather roll over to the other side as if it's a circular buffer" is unclear.  Please explain more on that concern.

Comment: The `>>` operator is always a shift, never a rotate (i.e. it always discards the rightmost bits).

Comment: It is not the machine code that determines how the C code behaves, but the other way around. Unsigned shifts in C are guaranteed to behave as logical shifts, regardless of what instructions the CPU support. The resulting machine code might be a ROR instruction but carry is then discarded. The only exception being signed right-shifts on negative numbers, where C doesn't specify what will happen - the compiler is then free to either use logical shift or arithmetic shift.

Comment: You may also try with unions, using something like `union { uint32_t u32; uint8_t u8[4]; } t; t.u32 = value;`

Comment: Isn't using unions for this purpose non-standard and completely compiler dependent?

Comment: Probably you're right, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540638/how-are-the-union-members-stored

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you presented is the most portable way of doing it. You convert a single unsigned integer value with 32 bits width into an array of unsigned integer values of exactly 8 bits width. The resulting bytes in the `buffer` array are in big endian order.

The masking is not needed. From [C11 6.5.7p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p5):

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has
>   a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
>   E1 / 2^E2.

and casting to an integer with 8 bits width is (to the value) equal to masking 8 bits. So `(result >> 24) & 0xff` is equal to `(uint8_t)(result >> 24)` (to the value). As you assign to `uint8_t` variable the masking is not needed. Anyway I would safely assume it will be optimized out by a sane compiler.

I can recommend to take a look at one implementation that I remembered, that I guess has implemented in a really safe manner all the possible variants of splitting and composing fixed-width integers up to 64 bits from bytes and back, that is at [gpsd bits.h](https://github.com/biiont/gpsd/blob/master/bits.h#L40).

Comment: The masking is often needed to silence compiler/static analyser warnings. For example a MISRA-C checker will even require that you use `(uint8_t)(value >> 24)` with an explicit conversion through cast.

Comment: MISRA  should be considered as a separate distinct language :).